# Firebase Auth working with WiFi but not with mobile data

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I get this error when I'm trying to login with mobile data on my Firebase App:
"A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."

My app was working perfectly until I tried to log in with mobile data on my new smartphone (It's working fine with my old one) and I'm running out of ideas concerning the source of the problem. Here are the things I've already tried"

1. Check data restrictions, data limit and permission.
2. Reset the APN.
3. Check Network Provider: I put my new SIM card in my older phone and it's working fine and when I was sharing that connection on my new Phone it was also working.
4. Check android version: I thought that maybe it was the Android version (API 28) of my new phone the problem but it's working fine for other users with API 28 version.
5. I also tried to change to 2G or 3G but not that didn't work.
6. Check google play services : it's activated

Here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.caroloucl"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Well, everything points to a device-only issue. The problem can be with web sockets, as using a VPN can solve the problem.

Comment: Yes @GauravMall, this is definitely linked with web sockets; for some of my users also face this issue, and it gets resolved when using a VPN.

But this is not a solution in itself, we cannot ask users to download and use a vpn to use our app...

Did anyone find a permanent fix / solution to this issue?